# MVC 3 File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I want to use mulitple File uploaders on my Razor view form. For this I tried File upload Web helper (@FileUpload.Gethtml()) but unable to call desired controller action. Any help on this or some other way will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple html form with multiple file upload inputs and set the form action to post your controlle action

For example

```
<div>
<h2>File Uploads Updates</h2>
<form action="/FileUpload/UploadMultiple" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">FileAt:</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileA" id="fileA" /><br />  
    <label for="file">FileB:</label>
    <input type="file" name="FileB" id="FileB" /><br />   

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</div>
```

See Also this [Hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) on how to do file uploads in MVC

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use third party controls, take a look into [Telerik upload control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/upload?theme=vista).
It is an open source one (GPL 2 ? license)